# can we show badge number on iPhone app using GCM notifications as APNS badge icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, badge

can we show badge number on iPhone app using GCM notifications as APNS badge icon

As I couldn't set this using GCM.
I have reffered [this link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref) which says

```
  Parameter      Platform          Usage                  Description

    badge         iOS             Optional,string   Indicates the badge on client app home icon.
```

I am receiving the notifications from GCM but badge icon is not shown when notifications are received in background state .

Can anyone please tell me how we can set this

Comment: Badge numbers do work, what is the message you're sending?

Comment: I am using http://gcm-alert.appspot.com/ to test and common message used for android and iOS as "Message" = "Hello message"

Comment: What I'm asking is what's the json you're sending? e.g. You would have to put `badge` in the `notification` dictionary of your message. e.g. `{ "notification" : { "body" : "Hello message", "badge" : "1" } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Badges do work. Here's my request, see how yours is different

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Authorization:key=XXXXXXXXX" "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send" --data-ascii '{"to":"YYYYYYYYYYYYY","data":{"custom-key":"custom-value"},"priority":10,"notification":{"body":"Hello","badge":"2"}}'
```